# How to use coordinates outside of didUpdateLocation function?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm trying to use the coordinates outside of `didUpdateLocations` function but I can not get it to work.

I try to declare the coordinates as a degree outside of the function but that does not work.

How can I get some guidance on this?

```
var currentUserLatitude:CLLocationDegrees?
var currentUserLongitude:CLLocationDegrees?

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    //location info about the user
    let location = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span:span)
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
// i want to use these variables outside the function
    var currentUserLatitude = location!.coordinate.latitude
    var currentUserLongitude = location!.coordinate.longitude

}
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with Java?

Comment: Clearly define "does not work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign values to the variables declared outside the local function, don't redeclare the variables as local variables.

Change these lines:

```
var currentUserLatitude = location!.coordinate.latitude
var currentUserLongitude = location!.coordinate.longitude
```

to:

```
currentUserLatitude = location!.coordinate.latitude
currentUserLongitude = location!.coordinate.longitude
```

Comment: rmaddy's answer is correct. You should accept it. When you use the word "var" or "let" you are creating a new variable. Your code has 2 different pairs of variables. One pair are instance variables, and the second pair are local variables in your didUpdateLocations function. By getting rid of the "var" keyword inside the didUpdateLocations function, your code is changing the instance variable like you want to.